# How do you monitor status and view logs for multiple distributed java applications at a centralized place?

Tags: java, distributed-systems

We have multiple java applications running on distributed hosts in our system. As theses applications are processing huge amount of data, it is designed this way. However, it had been a challenge in getting the status of these applications, view logs etc., across the different hosts.
All these applications uses log4j and is logging to a file in the hosted machine.
Is there a open source, proven solution that can be used to get status and view logs for distributed java applications at a centralized place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Glowroot](https://glowroot.org/)

Glowroot is Open source Java Application Monitor. Very easy to use and Very low overhead.

Steps to run:

1. Download and unzip [glowroot-0.13.4-dist.zip](https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot/releases/download/v0.13.4/glowroot-0.13.4-dist.zip)
2. add `-javaagent:path/to/glowroot.jar` to your application's JVM args
3. Go to http://localhost:4000
4. and monitor all this

Answer (score 0):

You could use [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/)  with the GELF logformat from your apps as central logserver, we do this with highly distributed systems. So you would be able to get errors and troughput metrics as graphs to. 
Or if you need more insights [pinpoint](https://github.com/naver/pinpoint)